# Bootstrap image gallery blank space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image gallery in Bootstrap that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuyCH.png

Only in the 2nd row, and on some screen sizes (like 992px to 1200px), there is an empty row like the one in the image. If I remove e.g. first two or three images in the inspector, everything evens nicely, but doing that in the code doesn't help.

Here's my code for this gallery:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/bunarska-visoki-pritisak.jpg">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/bunarska-visoki-pritisak.png" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Bunarska pumpa visokog pritiska</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/demontaza-bunarske-pumpe.jpg">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/demontaza-bunarske-pumpe.jpg" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Demontaza bunarske pumpe</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/dubinske-pumpe-liveno-gvozdje.jpg">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/dubinske-pumpe-liveno-gvozdje.png" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Dubinske pumpe od livenog gvozdja</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/frekventna-regulacija.JPG">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/frekventna-regulacija.JPG" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Frekventna regulacija</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/komandno-upravljacki-orman.JPG">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/komandno-upravljacki-orman.JPG" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Komandno upravljacki orman</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/opremanje-arterijskog-bunara.jpg">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/opremanje-arterijskog-bunara.png" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Opremanje arterijskog bunara</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/postavljanje-bunarske-pumpe.jpg">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/postavljanje-bunarske-pumpe.png" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Postavljanje bunarske pumpe</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/pustanje-u-rad-bunarske-pumpe.jpg">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/pustanje-u-rad-bunarske-pumpe.png" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Pustanje u rad bunarske pumpe</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 filter bunarske">
                    <a class="thumbnail fancybox" rel="ligthbox" href="../img/bunarske/vertikalna.JPG">
                        <img class="img-responsive" alt="" src="../img/bunarske/vertikalna.JPG" />
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <small class="text-muted">Vertikalna hidroforska posuda</small>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Everything is wrapped inside a container and a row. I use fancybox for the gallery, with jQuery.matchHeight plugin (https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) for making the heights even. I initialized it like this:

```
$(".thumbnail").matchHeight();
```

I tried many things including setting clearfix, padding, adding row, resizing images and whatnot. Surely it will turn out to be something very trivial, but I am failing to see what exactly. All the other images in other sections display fine.

Comment: fixed div 'height' and

Comment: and? :) I don't think it's a complete answer.

Comment: Can you create a working example please

Comment: @SahilDhir an already working example can be found here: http://f5167b60.ngrok.io/galerija/ and by clicking on the 5th item in the gallery menu (Bunarske pumpe). This anomaly happens only on that gallery item, everything else works fine - I wonder is it due to the size of the image? matchHeight should solve all of that dynamically, as images are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

create a div like this
 `.img-fixed {
    height: 190px;
    overflow: hidden;`
 
fixed height div try this one https://jsfiddle.net/r3vn2t5v/

Comment: This does not solve the problem, I already said that I use the jQuery.matchHeight plugin, so setting a height is not needed.

Comment: you have use same img and same text i thing this one working ?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue by displaying 3 images in a row, which not only looks better, but removes this weird blank space that appeared.